# How to collapse a cell group behind its 2nd cell with same functionality as WholeCellGroupOpener

Tags: notebooks, cells

Given a cell group containing two subcells...

1. If you double click the bracket of the first cell, you collapse the group behind the first cell in that group.
2. If, instead, you double click on the bracket of the second cell in that group you collapse that group behind the second cell in that group.

With WholeCellGroupOpener turned on...if you single click ANYWHERE in the first cell, you collapse that group behind the first cell in that group.

I would like to find a way to collapse the group behind the second cell by single-clicking anywhere in the second cell, basically achieving the same functionality as WholeCellGroupOpener.

Is this possible?

The animation below should help clarify my request.  The group has WholeCellGroupOpener turned on.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you might be able to do it with `CellEventActions` and the front-end token ``"SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"``. E.g. `SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell];FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"]`

Answer (score 1):

This'll kinda imitate it:

```
CellEventActions :> {
  "MouseClicked" :> Switch[CurrentValue["MouseClickCount"],
    1, 
     SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell];
     FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"],
    2,
     SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell];
     FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]
    ]
  }
```

If you click once it closes and if you double click it opens